# How can I have automatic snapshots with s3ql?

Tags: backup, s3ql

How can I make automatic snapshots with [s3ql](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/)? I want to have a similar behaviour as in duplicity: Pushing the backup to the server creates a new incremental snapshot with the current timestamp. Then I want to be able to browse and restore a specific backup version for example the snapshot of a given date.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official documentation](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/special.html).

*Excerpt from that doc*

> Note that:
>
> After the replication, both source and target directory will still be
>   completely ordinary directories. You can regard  as a snapshot of
>    or vice versa. However, the most common usage of s3qlcp is to
>   regularly duplicate the same source directory, say documents, to
>   different target directories. For a e.g. monthly replication, the
>   target directories would typically be named something like
>   documents_January for the replication in January, documents_February
>   for the replication in February etc. In this case it is clear that the
>   target directories should be regarded as snapshots of the source
>   directory.
>
> Exactly the same effect could be achieved by an ordinary copy program
>   like cp -a. However, this procedure would be orders of magnitude
>   slower, because cp would have to read every file completely (so that
>   S3QL had to fetch all the data over the network from the backend)
>   before writing them into the destination folder.

*Another excerpt*

> Snapshotting vs Hardlinking
>
> Snapshot support in S3QL is inspired by the hardlinking feature that
>   is offered by programs like rsync or storeBackup. These programs can
>   create a hardlink instead of copying a file if an identical file
>   already exists in the backup. However, using hardlinks has two large
>   disadvantages:
>
> backups and restores always have to be made with a special program
>   that takes care of the hardlinking. The backup must not be touched by
>   any other programs (they may make changes that inadvertently affect
>   other hardlinked files) special care needs to be taken to handle files
>   which are already hardlinked (the restore program needs to know that
>   the hardlink was not just introduced by the backup program to safe
>   space)